# Styling previous sibling on level above - Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I have this hierarchy:

```
<div>
  <label>Some label</label>
  <button><input/></button>
</div>
```

Is there a way to style the `label` with black color when the `input` is autofilled using Tailwind?

`peer` does not work here as `label` and `input` aren't peers.
I also tried JIT with native CSS on the label className: `[&+button>input:autofill~&]:text-black`, but it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You can't target previous siblings even if they were on the same level. You need to use `has` on the label or div.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a "previous sibling" selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector)